# Creating an SQLite Table from Android HTML Assets

Tags: android, html, sqlite

I tried to use an HTML in android to create a table in SQLite, but it is not working.

Sample HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      charset="utf-8"
      src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      // Wait for PhoneGap to load
      //
      //document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      // PhoneGap is ready
      //
      function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
      }

      // Populate the database
      //
      function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO");
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)");
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
      }

      // Transaction error callback
      //
      function errorCB(tx, err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
      }

      // Transaction success callback
      //
      function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onDeviceReady()">
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not able to see any database created in android 2.2.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

WebView has the ability to invoke java code through javascript code. How about trying this solution?

Answer (score 4):

I think your database created in android's cache directory, that's why to are unable to see it. So use WebView's setting method and make cache enable also give WebView's SQLite database path to your cache directory, then use your database.

---

1. Create a `WebView`,
2. Get the `webSettings`, and set the Database Path. The path should be the path to your databases, which will be `/path/path/your_package_name/`.

   ```java
   appView.setWebChromeClient(new WebClient(this));
   WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings();
               settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
               settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
               settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
               settings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/<database path>/app_database");
   ```
3. Create a `WebChromeClient`, and override the `onExceededDatabaseQuota` method. This is called when you first open the application, because there’s initially no database setup. This allows you to set the quota in Java. Since this was a test code, I just threw an arbitrary value in here.

   ```java
   final class WebClient extends WebChromeClient {
       Context mCtx;
       WebClient(Context ctx)
       {
           mCtx = ctx;
       }

       public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier,
           long currentQuota, long estimatedSize,
           long totalUsedQuota,WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater)
       {
           Log.d(LOG_TAG, "We exceeded the quota");
           quotaUpdater.updateQuota(100000);
       }
   }
   ```

---

For more details:

- [Joe Bowser's Blog — How To: Implement HTML5 Storage on a WebView with Android 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20111109214412/http://blogs.nitobi.com/joe/2009/11/05/how-to-implement-html5-storage-on-a-webview-with-android-2-0/).

Answer (score 0):

On rooted device go to :

1. DDMS
2. File Explorer
3. data ->data
4. package name
5. app_databases

Here "app_databases" contains "Databases.db" file that contains other databases files .