# Using PhoneGap for Android : Not able to create table in the database

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

BackGround : I am new to PhoneGap and trying to create a simple table in the SQLite using HTML5 + PhoneGap on Android.

Here is my HTML Code. (Using the reference code from PhoneGap site)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready


      function onDeviceReady() {


                navigator.notification.alert(
                        'Welcome to SQLLiteDemo',  // message
                        '',         // callback
                        'Hey -- Welcome123'             // title
                    );

        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
         tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(tx, err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
        console.log('It is failure'+err);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
    console.log('It is success');
        alert("success!");
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not able to see the table getting created and getting the below errors on the console.

> Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced
>   from method
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.getWhitelistResponse
>
> TypeError: Result of expression 'db' [null] is not an object. at
>   file:///android_asset/www/index.html:25
>
> Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced
>   from method
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.getWhitelistResponse
>
> TypeError: Result of expression 'db' [null] is not an object. at
>   file:///android_asset/www/index.html:22

I am not sure what does this error "

> Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced 
>   from method 
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.getWhitelistResponse

" wants to convey. I did not change my config.xml and did not put any entries in the whitelisted entries as I am not talking to any remote urls. Not sure weather this error can be ignore or not? :(

I am able to see the alert box using cordova, so there is not any issue related to integration with cordova but something weird is happening. Please help

**P.S - I am working with Android 2.3 on Emulator.**

Thanks
Gendaful

Comment: Have you checked this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775740/phonegap-cordova-2-0-0-android-apk-error

Comment: Yah.I have referred that. I have kept cordova.jar in libs folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution and i am posting it here.

Actually, the DB is getting created and is under '/data/data/package_name/' folder. I was searching it under '/data/data//databases' folder and that is the reason I was not able to see the table getting created.

[Creating SQLite Table from Android HTML Assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499899/creating-sqlite-table-from-android-html-assets?rq=1)

is good link and has helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I could be off base, but it appears that `window.openDatabase` is actually an HTML 5 feature of the browser.  It looks like your code:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
```

Is returning `null`.

From your Android 2.3 emulator, launch the device's web browser and go to `http://html5test.com/`, and see if web SQL database shows as supported.