# Where the sQLite database file created ,stored in jQuery Mobile Application

Tags: sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my jQuery Mobile App i have created sQlite Database and all transactions work successfully , and I want to see the DB file, I searched for it in my project directory but I didn't found it? Does phonegap create file for the created sqlite DB? and where is it? how I can pull the DB file  in order to see the inserted data?

I have searched over the internet but I didn't found any answer ,please help me .. since I am new in jQuery Mobile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on which platform u r trying?

Comment: Android , i have opened the App in eclipse , and searched for the DB but i didn't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your database is being created in android's cache directory. The following stackoverflow followup answer by the original questioner and it's backlink to an earlier answer should be all you need:

[Using PhoneGap for Android : Not able to create table in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740595/using-phonegap-for-android-not-able-to-create-table-in-the-database/16742016#16742016)